# Toggle function with UIButton programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, swift2, toggle

i'm newbies in swift and i wanted to make a toggle/switch function with a UIButton.

I've tried multiple method and i don't find the solution.

Could you help me for this please.

Here is my code (these buttons are declared in the viewDidLoad method):

```
let switchLightBT = UIButton()
switchLightBT.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 220, width: 102, height: 102))
switchLightBT.backgroundColor = .clear
switchLightBT.tag = 1
switchLightBT.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "dark-icon"), for: .normal)
switchLightBT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(darkTheme(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(switchLightBT)

let switchDarkBT = UIButton()
switchDarkBT.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 220, width: 102, height: 102))
switchDarkBT.backgroundColor = .clear
switchDarkBT.tag = 2
switchDarkBT.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "light-icon"), for: .normal)
switchDarkBT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(lightTheme(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(switchDarkBT)
```

and actions :

```
    func darkTheme(sender: UIButton!){
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
sender.isHidden = true
        for button in self.wbButtons {
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor .white, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func lightTheme(sender: UIButton!){
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
sender.isHidden = true
        for button in self.wbButtons {
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor .black, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Just for a preview, without this code (declared in the viewDidLoad method too), that i want work fine but ONE TIME and i want this work all the time.

```
if switchDarkBT.isSelected == false {
    switchDarkBT.isHidden = false
    switchLightBT.isHidden = true
} else {
    switchDarkBT.isHidden = true
    switchLightBT.isHidden = false

}
```

Comment: What is `self.wbButtons`

Comment: It's an outlet collections of multiple buttons.

Comment: what you want after button clicked?

Comment: you want to one hide and one unhide button when click on button?

Comment: Hi, i wanted to hide/disable "switchLightBT" and display "switchDarkBT" and vice-versa.

Comment: For switch function use [UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswitch)

Comment: I know this, but i want use UIButton for UI exigence.

Comment: you can declare switchLightBT,switchDarkBT instance variable.so you can easily access them in darkTheme,lightTheme method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
let switchLightBT = UIButton() 
let switchDarkBT = UIButton() 

override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 
switchLightBT.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 220, width: 102, height: 102)) 
switchLightBT.backgroundColor = .clear 
switchLightBT.tag = 1 
switchLightBT.setImage(UIImage(named:"light"), for: .normal) 
switchLightBT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(darkTheme(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
self.view.addSubview(switchLightBT) 

switchDarkBT.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 220, width: 102, height: 102)) 
switchDarkBT.backgroundColor = .clear 
switchDarkBT.tag = 2 
switchLightBT.setImage(UIImage(named:"dark"), for: .normal) 
switchDarkBT.addTarget(self, action: #selector(lightTheme(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) 

self.view.addSubview(switchDarkBT) 

} 

func darkTheme(sender: UIButton!){ 
self.view.backgroundColor = .black 
switchLightBT.isHidden = true 
switchDarkBT.isHidden = false 

} 

func lightTheme(sender: UIButton!){ 
self.view.backgroundColor = .white 
switchLightBT.isHidden = false 
switchDarkBT.isHidden = true 

}
```

Comment: Yes, but after first action (first touchUpInside), all buttons disappears ! and i need to toggle buttons - if "switchDarkBT" is hidden, display "switchLightBT" and vice-versa !

Comment: Where have you created these two buttons? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Have you added these two buttons in self.wbButtons?

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I would like! I don't want hide the collections of buttons, I just want to switch the two buttons which activated/deactivated a color theme that i've configured!


When I press the "switchDarkBT" button it activates the color theme A and this same button disappears and lets appear the "switchLightBT" button, and so on ...

Comment: switchDarkBT and switchLightBT is created in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Does self.wbButtons contains these two buttons? These two buttons don't have title and you are changing titlecolor in for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141323/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-gilbertool).

Comment: No, these two buttons don't belong to "wbButtons", these two buttons are totally independant !

Comment: I've edited my question, more easily to understand now ! Just remove a part of code in viewDidLoad method and uncomment sender.isHidden = true in two actions method and you will see that i want !!! BUT only one time, and i want this work all the time !

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the switchLightBT and switchDarkBT as instance variables and add these lines to your button functions.

```
func darkTheme(sender: UIButton!){
        switchDarkBT.isHidden = true
        switchLightBT.isHidden = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        for button in self.wbButtons {
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor .white, for: .normal)
        }
    }

func lightTheme(sender: UIButton!){
        switchLightBT.isHidden = true
        switchDarkBT.isHidden = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        for button in self.wbButtons {
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor .black, for: .normal)
        }
        }
```

Comment: Like this :

    var switchDarkBT = Bool()
    var switchLightBT = Bool()

Comment: Oops sorry, like this :  var switchDarkBT = UIButton()
    var switchLightBT = UIButton()